# not able to send or receive data from real server in eclipse but the same program executes fine on localhost

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this code works fine for localhost but gives some warnings and not able to send or receive any data from server. php file is able to display the message when the link http://*****/check.php is called. but not able to display anything when called from the server.

```
try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/check.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void showAlert(){
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
            builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

the warning it gives are
logs-

```
W/SingleClientConnManager(312): Invalid use 
of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
W/SingleClientConnManager(312): Make sure to release 
the  connection before allocating another one.
D/dalvikvm(312): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3302 objects / 175320 bytes in 153ms
D/dalvikvm(203): GC_EXPLICIT freed 203 objects / 13616 bytes in 137ms
I/System.out(312): Exception : Internal Server Error
W/InputManagerService(58): Window already focused,   ignoring focus gain 
of:   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43fd5720
D/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 761 objects / 55032 bytes in 150ms
D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: `Exception : Internal Server Error` means it's probably to do with your server setup rather than your client code.

Comment: i have checked the php connection and rest of the things. it seems to be alright. so not able to figure out the reason behind internal server error

Comment: You might want to try posting another question about your server and include your PHP script. `Internal Server Error` means there is definitely something wrong with your server and/or your script. Someone with better understanding of PHP problems might be able to help you,